# Distance between parametric function and a point

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given a parametric function
$$\begin{align*}
x &= x_o + v_x t + \frac{1}{2}  a_x  t^2\\
y &= y_o + v_y t + \frac{1}{2}  a_y  t^2\end{align*}$$

and point $P$ at $(c, d)$ , find all point(s) on the function that are distance $R$ from point $P$, assuming that $R > 0$ and none of the constants equal $0$.

This is part of a programming project (that I'm doing on my own, not for homework), so the answer needs to be obtainable using only expressions. Graphically solving the problem won't be possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I'm note sure if `(homework)`.</strike>

**Hint:**

I'm assuming that we're given $R, c, d, x_0, v_x, a_x, y_0, v_y, a_y.$

The squared distance between $P = (c,d)$ and $(x,y)$ is given by
$$ R^2 = (x - c)^2 + (y - d)^2 \tag{1}$$
Substitute the definition of $$x = x_o + v_x * t + \frac{1}{2} * a_x * t^2  \tag{2} \\ y =  y_o + v_y * t + \frac{1}{2} * a_y * t^2$$ in $(1) $

You're left with a polynomial in $t.$ Solve for $t,$ this will give you different values of $t = \{t_1, \ldots, t_4\}.$ Substitute each $t_i$ in $(2)$ to get different $(x,y)$ points.

---

**Update # 1:**

I'm too lazy to LaTeX the following equation:

```
        2          2   4                            3
(0.25 ay  + 0.25 ax ) t  + (1.0 vy ay + 1.0 vx ax) t

      2                                       2               2
 + (vx  + 1.0 xo ax - 1.0 ax c - 1.0 ay c + vy  + 1.0 yo ay) t

                                                    2       2       2
 + (-2. vy c + 2. yo vy + 2. xo vx - 2. vx c) t + xo  + 2. c  - 1. R

                  2
 - 2. xo c - 2. yo   = 0
```

Anyways, that's the degree $4$ polynomial in $t.$ To find a closed-form expressions for the roots $$\{t_1 = \cdots, t_2 = \cdots, t_3 = \cdots, t_4 = \cdots\},$$ you will need to do a lot of algebra on this polynomial. [For example this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_polynomial#Ferrari.27s_solution).

Comment: The problem is that because this is for a program, each possible value of $t$ must be defined as a single expression ($t1 = ..., t2 = ...$) using $R,c,d,x_0,v_x,a_x,y_0,v_y,a_y$.
The numerical values for these constants are unknown, since the values will vary when this is used in the program.
The problem that I'm facing is that when I take the expanded polynomial and solve for $t$ using my graphing calculator, it is unable to find a solution.

Comment: @JonW I added some more comments to my answer,.

Comment: Thanks. I found [this](http://www.1728.org/quartic2.htm) thing, which I think I might be able to use. Since the massive equation basically follows $A * t^4 + B * t^3 + C * t^2 + D * t + E = 0$, I could probably use the method described to solve the problem. All of the constants ARE numerical values, so I can just plug them in to find the numerical values for A, B, C, D, and E.

Comment: @JonW Indeed.  The big expression above gives you $A, B, C, D, E.$ You're on the right path.